# JFreeChart: Updating DomainAxis

Tags: java, plot, jfreechart

How to define `DomainAxis` in such a way that only each 10th category is shown?

```
    final CategoryItemRenderer renderer = new CategoryStepRenderer(true);
    final CategoryAxis domainAxis = new CategoryAxis("Time");
    domainAxis.setLowerMargin(0.0);
    domainAxis.setUpperMargin(0.0);
    final ValueAxis rangeAxis = new NumberAxis("Net demand");
    rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
    final CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot(dataset, domainAxis, rangeAxis, renderer);
    final JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Category Step Chart", plot);

    Title t = new TextTitle("Subtitle");
    chart.addSubtitle(t);

    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

    plot.setForegroundAlpha(0.5f);
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
    plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(true);
    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
    plot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(true);
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
```

Comment: Your code seems lacking. Why do you need to have all the data present in the data objects if you are only showing every 10th?  Give more context.

Comment: @D-Klotz: I may loose some data if I add only 10th entry in the data object. However, I just need to type only 10th data label in the DomainAxis.

Comment: So do I understand correctly, you wish to have the data but change what 'tick marks' appear? If so, then I misunderstood your original question.

Comment: Also, what I suggest, is make a simple standalone code example that I can copy and paste (and it compiles) that shows your problem. Just use dummy data. I've used jfree chart for years but I need to see a more complete code example if I'm going to help.